# UIProgressView is not updating in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, uiprogressview

In my project am downloading data from server, downloading code is in App Delegate.m file and 
once am passing downloading status(in bytes) to NSNotification object. In my ViewController am trying to update UIProgressView using the above downloading status. When i log Downlaoding status (bytes downloaded) am getting correct value. But when i tried to show that in UIProgressView and its not showing anything.

Code

App delegate.m

```
 ViewController *viewC=[[ViewController alloc]init];
[viewC postNotificationWithValue:bytesDownloaded:totalSize];
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _progreeView.progress = 0.0; //UIProgressView

    NSString *notificationName = @"MTPostNotificationTut";

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(useNotificationWithString:)
     name:notificationName
     object:nil];
}





- (void)postNotificationWithString:(NSUInteger )current:(NSUInteger )total {


   //   NSLog(@"%f",(double)current/(double)total);
    float status=(double)current/(double)total;
    _downloadStatus.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",status];

[_progreeView  setProgress:status animated:YES];
}
```

and my UIProgressbar is not updating at all. Pls help me

Comment: You just create a viewController and than setup it's slider value? And what about the view and viewController initialization process? You have to setup the viewController's view to be presented before you update the progress indicator on an animated way... Please, start to build a simple iOS app based on http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Comment: i have lots of contents in viewcontroller and delegaet but i show only relevent contents here

Answer (score 1):

Have u check if the `_progreeView` isn't `nil`?!
Why not load the `ViewController` from `nib` :

```
NSArray *viewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController"
                                                   owner:self 
                                                  options:nil];

ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)[viewArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Anyway, Without go too deep with your code, I think that the problem is because that u don't update the UI from the main thread.
Make sure that u updating:

```
[_progreeView  setProgress:status animated:YES];
```

From the **MAIN** thread.

Any UI changes must be on the main thread - Remember that!

So u can wrap that like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [_progreeView  setProgress:status animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: its not working..i drag and drop one UIView into my ViewController and on that i have added UIProgressView

Comment: Have u check if whether your `_progreeView` isn't `nil`??

Comment: Ask yourself if u did so ;)